# Partial differential equation with boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am stuck on this PDE. The text says to use separation of variables, but I cannot figure out how to get the extra terms that show up in the solution.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+u\\
u(x,0) = 3e^{-5x}+2e^{-3x}$$

Solution:

$$u=3e^{-5x-3y}+2e^{-3x-2y}$$

I use separation of variables and get $u=Ce^{\frac{\lambda}{2}(2x+y)}$. Then, I try using $u=e^{(ax+by)}$, I get $u=e^{b(2x+y)}$. So, I keep getting that the exponential has the form $2x+y$, but I am stuck on how the solution is reached from th3 given boundary condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the coordinate transformation

$$
\cases{\eta = x\\
\xi = c x + y
}
$$

we have $v(\eta,\xi) = u(x,y)$

$$
v_{\eta}+(c-2)v_{\xi}=v
$$

then choosing $ c = 2$ we have

$$
v_{\eta}=v
$$

with solution

$$
v(\eta,\xi) = \phi(\xi) e^{\eta}
$$

or

$$
v(x,\xi) = \phi(\xi) e^x
$$

and the condition

$$
u(x,0) = v(x,2x) = \phi(2x)e^x = 3e^{-5x}+2e^{-3x}\Rightarrow \phi(x) = 3e^{-3x}+2e^{-2x}
$$

gives

$$
u(x,y) = e^x\phi(2x+y) = 3e^{-5x-3y}+2e^{-3x-2y}
$$